# VPN from Home Network

Tags: vpn

I don't know if this is the correct StackExchange but I was wondering if anyone could provide a guide or let me know if it is even possible to create a personal VPN that would be running from a computer on my home network and would allow me to pass all of my traffic through my home network, as if I was physically at home connected to that network. Is this possible at all and if so, how would you go about doing this?

Comment: I use a Cisco 881 ISR as my home router and it is setup to use the Cisco IPSEC VPN client. I also use dnsdynamic.com (because it's free) to update my IP. From there it is really simple to connect to my own VPN and access everything at home.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. To use a computer as the end point you would want to look into something like [Open VPN](http://openvpn.net). After configuring that on your PC you would then need to forward the ports for VPN from your router to your PC. I would also configure something like [No-IP](https://www.noip.com) so you have an easy to remember DNS name to connect to.

*Another option:*
Personally I use a Cisco ASA for my home/work VPN. I think this is a better solution but it would cost money (decent ASA5505 can be had on eBay for ~$200 if you're patient). This would replace your home router and would be both the router and VPN endpoint.